# Dynamic keys in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have some formData object like this (I'm getting it in runtime):

```
const formData = {
  xAxisColumn: 'abc',
  periodColumn: 'cde'
};
```

And data that I'm getting from the server that has the next structure:

```
const response = {
  abc: 'some data 1',
  cde: 123,
  otherColumn: 'bla...'
}
```

I'm trying in Typescript to create a type for the response object where the keys are dynamic and based on formData values.

Something like:

```
type TResponse<T, U> = {
 [T]: string;
 [U]: number;
}
```

But this is incorrect for TS, so how can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting this ``` xAxisColumn: 'abc',``` at runtime?

Comment: @Drag13 yes, when get response

Comment: TypeScript doesn't exist in runtime. You can't do anything.

Comment: @Drag13 Ok. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing exactly how the rest of your code would make use of it, the type you're looking for could be expressed like this:

```
type TResponse<KS extends PropertyKey, KN extends PropertyKey> = 
  Record<KS, string> & Record<KN, number>;
```

that's an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) of two [`Record`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkt) types.  It says that `TResponse<KS, KN>` has a `string` property at the key of type `KS`, and a `number` property at the key of type `KN`.

---

You could possibly then use it like this:

```
const formData = {
  xAxisColumn: 'abc',
  periodColumn: 'cde'
} as const;

const response = {
  abc: 'some data 1',
  cde: 123,
  otherColumn: 'bla...'
}

function processResponse<KS extends PropertyKey, KN extends PropertyKey>(
  formData: { xAxisColumn: KS, periodColumn: KN },
  response: TResponse<KS, KN>
) {
  const xAxis: string = response[formData.xAxisColumn];
  const period: number = response[formData.periodColumn];
  // ... process them here
}

processResponse(formData, response); // okay
processResponse({ xAxisColumn: "x", periodColumn: "p" }, { x: "okay", p: 123 }); // also okay
processResponse({ xAxisColumn: "x", periodColumn: "p" }, { x: 123, p: 456 }); // error!
// number is not assignable to string -------------------> ~
```

Or maybe

```
function keyVal<K extends PropertyKey, V>(key: K, val: V) {
  return { [key]: val } as Record<K, V>;
}

function makeResponse<KS extends PropertyKey, KN extends PropertyKey>(
  formData: { xAxisColumn: KS, periodColumn: KN }
): TResponse<KS, KN> {
  return Object.assign(keyVal(formData.xAxisColumn, "x axis data"), keyVal(formData.periodColumn, 123));
}
```

The point of the example code is to show that the compiler will enforce the constraint that `response` is of the right shape given the values of `formData`... as long as the compiler knows the [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) values of `formData`.  You will find `TResponse<KS, KN>` much easier to use when `KS` and `KN` are known literal types.

Inside the implementation of `processResponse()` and `makeResponse()`, where `KS` and `KN` are unspecified generic types, it becomes more difficult for the compiler to reason about `TResponse<KS, KN>` and you need to find roundabout ways to express manipulating properties of unspecified keys, possibly involving [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) as in `keyVal()` above.

So while you *can* express `TResponse`, it might not be worth it to do so.

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiATgWwCIEMrpgXhgbwCgYYAPAQVIEsIBhEAGwFdkwAuGAcnQCNhOANMRgAHAKaIqIACb1mrDp2DSxnQgF8Y6CDFCQoAbkKE90GIjEQR4CGNwFhvYIoghkd6ZmwBGQcOViHN4ATADMQiQgUAAWEnIs7Fw8DOgAdOlq6sZQAJ7iMAAqAEqW1pBiADwA0gDKMGKkUGJg0joACogg4oi5VWI5AjBVAHL1jc2tMB1dEr39AHz2JaCI0tU1g9CSYADmiwBkMMtIayODYCw8EvNGhHBMYMBQUmCincCWECVWNpW1Y00Wu1Ot05gMhqMGoDJtNQTk+jl5gAKYQIFAYLAcfBkSg0eIKIYbUQSKSyRgJDgjGDqCLmUq-DjFenldaDEbzQgASgcJFMsAo1AgHC2VF29gsP3KAG00WgvKkBXjyawALpGXk2WDdUkcC7IK6IcXM2wypByrCpbUyfFgNUaGDGETvT7fMq2JGyjHoQYSt1iTkGGAAeiDMBAAGt0DlCE6QB8IF9jWIkdjFXRlYkAESkTODK1k+RZkSZ6mDVMcTMRqO50RBMLUgPB0PoBiuMOR6Ox+OJyXu1O49OFis5vMk60ZivF0sEMh18K1mAAFgArAA2BuBkP1RCdRAAQkIW71BpgNBgYCiWgTVB2YF4DDsUBAMBFYoAtB-P1-v1-FgA-Yx7keZ5wBgcN+gANRbaoAQmYEZh6eF+kGCDkXAnJKUGAA3FsOAg7kiBICwoCYRBXmxKV0JVDgcIYakryOMQVlOFCbg0QCHieF4YGQdBwNdX51lgoEphBWYkPBKkoTg0SELBZFUTNL0sRxQUbUpIl83UiFqS5RkBJZWo2WGRZCLpEiyJgAB5HgACsmKgVJtAgG8wCRdCoIYD0lPlNMbUGbMtEFGBPCwTNOUGDyW289F5S0jNBhCUJOQDDQgA)